# On what factors is the communication protocol selected while establishing a Topic?

Tags: ros, tcpros, ros-kinetic, udpros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On what factors is the communication protocol selected ? be it TCP or UDP. Are there some other protocols supported as well ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288808/on-what-factors-is-the-communication-protocol-selected-while-establishing-a-topic-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: this *only* answers the question in the context of ROS 1.

---

> On what factors is the communication protocol selected ? be it TCP or UDP

Default is TCP (ie: `reliable`).

Unless user specifies the *unreliable* [transport hint](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Transport_Hints).

> Are there some other protocols supported as well ?

No, not by default.

There are some alternative transports available, but you'd have to install those yourself (they're old, but see [ethzasl_message_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_message_transport) fi).

See also [ROS/Technical Overview - Topic Transports](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Topic_Transports).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-18**:
@gvdhoorn : Then isnt ROS similar to the ROS2 QoS in respect to the Communication Protocol ? Both can either select reliablity (TCP) or Best Effort (UDP) ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
Well .. they're similar like a car is similar to a bike: both have wheels, but I wouldn't say that a bike shares much of the other characteristics of a car.

If you really want to, you could see `TCPROS` and `UDPROS` as primitive forms of what DDS can do for you. But I wouldn't do that.